# Where can I find US election results by county from before 1920?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, data-sources

While researching US election data, I found out there is no data for US presidential elections down to county level for elections before 1920.

Is this data hard to find or it does not exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up developing a simple web application for this data, it includes an API for developers too.

https://electionsbycounty.com

Comment: Wow!  I was not expecting a useful answer that did not involve a DeLorean and a Flux Capacitor.  Nice job.

Comment: Is there still an API? I can't find it on the site.